# comparing php variable in sql query

Tags: php

I am trying to compare php variable in the sql query as follows:
I have used '$a' as the way to compare. Any solution will provided will be quite helpful.

```
<?php
    $username=$_SESSION['alogin'];
    $sql = "SELECT kDepartment FROM USERS WHERE kUsername=:username ";
    $query= $dbh -> prepare($sql);
    $query-> bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();
    $results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    if($query->rowCount() > 0)
    {
        foreach($results as $result2)
        $a=$result2;
        {?>
  <?php }}?>

<?php

$sql2 = "SELECT BudgetInput.kBudgetAvailable FROM BudgetInput WHERE BudgetInput.kDepartment='$a' ";
$query2 = $dbh -> prepare($sql2);
$query2->execute();
$results2=$query2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
print htmlentities($a);
?>
```

I am unable to fetch the result.[image]

When I remove `WHERE BudgetInput.kDepartment='$a';` the UI works correctly.
[image]

Comment: So what's your problem exactly?

Comment: First, please explain your question. What isn’t working?  Second, you are wide open to [**SQL injection**](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection). You need to use prepared statements, rather than concatenating variables into your query. Simply escaping your variables is not enough. See [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1). (The first query in your code is done correctly; the second is not.)

Comment: @EdCottrell I have updated the question, I did realised I posted an incomplete question.

Comment: @NikitaLeshchev I did realised that I have posted an incomplete question.

Comment: Why not use one query and `JOIN` instead?

Comment: I thought  `JOIN` will make it more complex.

Comment: A `JOIN` would reduce the code and only perform one query, which is better than sending two queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue that I can see with your code is that you are assigning an object (`$result2` is the last entry in the array of objects returned by your query) to `$a` and then trying to use that as a string (I'm not sure why you're using `PDO::FETCH_OBJ` for your `fetchAll` call when you are only retrieving a single value but that's another question). Anyway, the `fetchAll` will return an anonymous object (see the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)) with one property, `kDepartment`. To use that value, change:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT BudgetInput.kBudgetAvailable FROM BudgetInput WHERE BudgetInput.kDepartment='$a' ";
```

to

```
$sql2 = "SELECT BudgetInput.kBudgetAvailable FROM BudgetInput WHERE BudgetInput.kDepartment='{$a->kDepartment}' ";
```

The other (minor) issue that I see is that you are using `rowCount`. This is not guaranteed to work for `SELECT` statements (see the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)) and since you have already done a `fetchAll` you don't need it, you can simply change

```
if($query->rowCount() > 0)
```

to

```
if (count($results) > 0)
```

Comment: Great. Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is a simple join - then you need one query instead of two. A query from the result of another query is rarely the best approach.

Here we prepare a query which selects the available budget from the `BudgetInput` table, where it has a matching `kDpeartment` in the `USERS` table, and a username matching the variable in `$username`.

```
<?php 
session_start();
$username = $_SESSION['alogin'];
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT bi.kBudgetAvailable 
                       FROM BudgetInput bi
                       JOIN USERS u ON u.kDepartment=bi.kDepartment
                       WHERE u.kUsername=?");
$stmt->execute([$username]);
if ($result = $stmt->fetch()) {
    echo $result['kBudgetAvailable'];
} else {
    echo "No results found";
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Qirel for your answer.